# is that possible in salesforce (passing inline string values to component)?

Tags: visualforce-component

I have component in my org, which accept list of string to process.

i am using the utility as follow

```
    <c:mycomponent  listOfName = "{!NameStrList}"/>
```

**code :**

```
list<string> NameStrList = new list<string>{'Name1','Name2'};
```

Now i want to show this use case to other developer. Then i thought the below

no code , just define list of string inline in component

**Expected** :

```
<c:myComponent listOfName ="{'Name','Name2'}" />
```

the above throw error.

Will it possible.? Just for curiosity, looking other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do that you are just passing a **string**, not the `Object List<String>`.

The compiler only knows what you pass it and you defined it as a list of strings. If you want to pass a string value, you can use string as the attribute type and pass in a JSON serialize string for the List but that is overkill and more work than just passing in the List.